# Why was my custom comment cleanup flag declined, although the comments were deleted?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, comment-flags

[On this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57203366/965146) I flagged one of the comments as:

> Comment clean up. Almost all comment is NLN. Heat detected. Thanks.

All comments moved to chat and are deleted now.

[One of our MODs also agree with this as per this chat comment:](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197017/discussion-on-answer-by-sotos-exclude-columns-from-apply-function-based-on-colum)

> okay, comments were deleted as it was leading nowhere except to a war.
>   Please take it to meta if you think it's worth it.

But my flag is declined. Why?

Comment: I see what happened there. Other users also had flagged that exact comment and that mod wanted to decline those which is why they declined yours as well. We can't decline individual comment flags. I'll let that mod know of your post.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Something weird must have happened since your flag made me delete the whole toxic conversation.

So it was definitely helpful.

As Bhargav comments:

> I see what happened there. Other users also had flagged that exact comment and that mod wanted to decline those which is why they declined yours as well. We can't decline individual comment flags.

Now I think I remember that each involved party flagged other comments as unfriendly but I had to decline them all prior to deleting the whole conversation, and your flag got caught in the crossfire.

Yes, your flag should have been marked "helpful". Sorry. You can have it in writing from me.

[image]

Comment: Would you recommend making this one a post flag in the future, rather than a comment flag?

Comment: that crossed my mind. Post flag need reason to decline. Harder to miss

Comment: Thanks for crossfire me and again thanks for honest reply :)

Comment: A freehand ___blue___ cross? What is this blasphemy!? #teamred

Comment: @Cerbrus he's such a rebel! :D

Comment: @E_net4 I encourage users to flag a comment for a comment thread clean up. They are addressed much faster

Comment: @YvetteColomb I understand, but sometimes such comment flags are automatically resolved without moderator intervention, deleting only one of the comments in the process.

Comment: @E_net4 true, but I do handle a lot of those flag types

Answer (score 12):

What has actually happened is what [Bhargav](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4099593/bhargav-rao) referred to in [his comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387726/why-is-my-comment-cleanup-flag-declined#comment715839_387726).

> I see what happened there. Other users also had flagged that exact comment and that mod wanted to decline those which is why they declined yours as well. We can't decline individual comment flags. I'll let that mod know of your post.

There were unkind flags on some of the comments that had custom flags on them. Moderators are unable to decline one flag and mark another one helpful on the same comment. They are either all declined or all marked helpful.

[image]

[image]

In this case the moderator appears to have missed one that didn't need to be declined. This happens to the best of us.

[image]

Also see [Can we handle flags on the same comment separately?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319111/can-we-handle-flags-on-the-same-comment-separately)

Comment: So as per system design there is always high chance to get declined  for comment cleanup flag ?

Comment: @Shree not really, I tend to mark them as helpful. The thing with comment flags is, they do not count towards a flag ban, so take them with a grain of salt. It in no way affects your account or flagging ability. Easy for me to say, but helpful unkind flags end up tripping an auto flag for a user if there's too many, so we are more selective on declining those if at all unsure. Personally I'd have marked the unkind flags as helpful and deleted the lot. Not sure if that reassures you

Comment: Ahh thanks. I always want to keep SO clean so never stop to flag . Around 32K+ helpful flag  , I don't think 1/2 flag declined banned me to flag. I just want to know what happen in this case.

Comment: @Shree you are one of the flaggers I can rely on. When going through the queue, when certain names are on a flag it tells me there's a good chance the flag is warranted. It alleviates some of the strain of constantly making judgement calls, as there's an opinion already on the flag I know is reliable and consistent. So thank you :)

Comment: Is it just me who finds that first comment having bad enough a tone to warrant a U/U flag? Harsh accusations of being a liar, excessive use of exclamation points, these are all red flags to me (no pun intended).

Comment: @E_net4 absolutely. I would have marked them as helpful